# Redirect in htaccess to real page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

What I have - URL like

```
http://example.com/index.php/anywords/anywords/anyname.php
```

or

```
http://example.com/index.php/anywords/anywords/
```

or

```
http://example.com/index.php/
```

What I want to have - redirect to

```
http://example.com/index.php
```

My current htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)/$
    RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please post your htaccess file which you have tried in your question?

Comment: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)/$
 RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L]
</IfModule>` but this is only solved by the last url

Comment: Thanks for sharing, you could add these in your question for better understanding cheers.

Answer (score 0):

***Generic solution for matching any words:*** Could you please try following. I have mentioned temporary redirect here, you could remove it if you don't want redirect on browser level.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php/([\w-]+/){1,}/[\w]+\.php/? [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php/([\w-]+/){1,}/? [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^index\.php/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [R=302,NC,L]
```

---

---

***For specific words:*** Could you please try following.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php/anywords/anywords/anyname\.php/? [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php/anywords/anywords/?$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^index\.php/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [R=302,NC,L]
```

Comment: anywords - it random words. I need to replace any words

Comment: @IndianGuy, ohh ok :) let me add for that now :)

Comment: I need to delete everything that comes after php if it doesn't look like parameters

Comment: @IndianGuy "if it doesn't look like parameters" - presumably you mean a _query string_ (ie. everything after a `?`)?

Comment: @MrWhite yes, i need to redirect to the first occurrence of php

Comment: @IndianGuy, could you please do mention url(with sample values) which is looking wise same as your actual url, my posted rules are working for your question, let me know on same.

Comment: "delete everything that comes after php" - providing this starts with a slash (as in the examples), then this is "additional pathname information" (aka. path-info). This can be trapped with a much simpler regex (in fact, no need for any _conditions_, since it can all be done in the `RewriteRule`). eg. `^index\.php/`

Comment: @IndianGuy, Hi, could you please do let us know on these previous comment's questions here?